# Write a formula for finding a function from a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

I have a block matrix T:

\begin{equation*}
T=\begin{pmatrix}
A & H \\
0 & B
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_{n,n}, B_{m,m}, H_{n,m}, 0_{m,n}.
\end{equation*}

I need to find a function from a given matrix. For example, $2x+3$. I found the following formula:
\begin{equation*}
f(T)=\begin{pmatrix}
f(A) & f^{[1]}(A,B)\diamond H \\
0 & f(B)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
According to the task, you need to find the function from the matrix in two ways:

1. Just calculate the function from the entire matrix (i.e. do the operation f(T))
2. Do manipulations with each block as according to the formula.

And here I don't understand the formula $f^{[1]}(A,B)\diamond H$. Yes, this is a divided difference, that's understandable. But how can this divided difference be applied to matrices? Can someone describe how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the $\diamond$ operator, and how is $f(x)=2x+3$ relate to $T$. I don't understand.

Comment: I can't remember the name of this symbol anymore, but it shows the possibility of an operation between two matrices of different dimensions. We can say that H is a transition matrix, so that, for example, we can multiply A by B

Comment: Regarding the 2x+3 function: in this case, we mean 2 * T + IdentityMatrix[Lenght[T]]*3

Comment: So for $f(x) = 2x + 3$ then $$ f(T)=\begin{pmatrix}
2 A+3 & 2 H \\
0 & 2 B + 3
\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Finding immediately f(T) without dividing into blocks, I also noticed that it would be 2H. But what if the function is different? for example, 6x^3-7.5x+13? I don't really understand how the function for H. is built then.

Comment: If ${\bf 1}$ is the identity matrix, then you just evaluate $$6 {\bf T}\,{\bf T}\,{\bf T} - 7.5\,{\bf T} + 13 {\bf 1}$$

Comment: I 'm talking in this case about H. H should be calculated using a different formula. And for matrices A and B, the formula will really look like $6TTT-7.5T+13*IdentityMatrix$

Comment: You can calculate $\lambda {\bf T}$ easily as well as adding a constant $\alpha\,\text{(Identity)}$. Your question is really how to calculate the off-diagonal block for ${\bf T}^n$. Please [edit] the question to make it clear what is the real issue is here.

Comment: Applying divided differences to matrices in this case: Solve the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) $AX-XB=f(A)H-Hf(B)$ for $X.$ This works unless $A$ and $B$ share an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a general polynomial matrix function $f(x) = \sum_{n =0}^p a_n x^n$ then you need a way to calculate $T^n$ for an integer $n \ge 0$.

You can use induction to find a recursive relationship.

Start with the following sequence

$$ \begin{aligned}T^{0} & =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
T^{1} & =\begin{bmatrix}A & H\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}\\
T^{2} & =\begin{bmatrix}A & H\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A & H\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}AA & AH+HB\\
0 & BB
\end{bmatrix}\\
T^{3} & =\begin{bmatrix}A^{2} & AH+HB\\
0 & B^{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A & H\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A^{3} & A^{2}H+\left(AH+HB\right)B\\
0 & B^{3}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\vdots
\end{aligned}
 $$

and by designating $H_n$ the upper right block matrix of $T^n$ then we have

$$\begin{aligned}T^{n-1} & =\begin{bmatrix}A^{n-1} & H_{n-1}\\
 & B^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}\\
T^{n} & =\begin{bmatrix}A^{n-1} & H_{n-1}\\
 & B^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A & H\\
 & B
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A^{n} & A^{n-1}H+H_{n-1}B^{n-1}\\
 & B^{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

which leads to the following recurrence relationship, with initial conditions $H_0 = 0$ and $H_1 = H$

$$ \boxed{ H_{n}=A^{n-1}H+H_{n-1}B^{n-1} }$$

to be used in

$$ T^n =\begin{bmatrix}A^n & H_n\\
 0 & B^n
\end{bmatrix} $$

or specifically

$$ f(T)=\sum_{n=0}^{p}a_{n}T^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{p}\begin{bmatrix}a_{n}A^{n} & a_{n}H_{n}\\
0 & a_{n}B^{n}
\end{bmatrix} $$